# `mpstat` sometimes shows above 100% CPU usage

Tags: linux, redhat, central-processing-unit

Running `mpstat -P ALL` on one of our servers returns the following:

```
06:48:02 AM  CPU   %user    %nice   %sys    %iowait  %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
06:48:02 AM  all    15.61   0.08    84.09   7.20     0.56    0.01    0.00   13.97    763.27
06:48:02 AM    0    12.40   0.07    82.12   8.26     0.41    0.01    0.00   13.21    341.40
06:48:02 AM    1    18.82   0.04    86.06   6.15     0.72    0.01    0.00   14.73    421.87
```

So total CPU usage is, as measured by the sums of each row's *percentages*:

all - 122.52%
CPU1 - 116.48%
CPU2 - 126.53%

Have I miss-understood how mpstat works? I thought the totals should always add up to 100%?

If it's relevant, the server is RHEL 5.5. CPU is Intel Xeon Dual Core L3406 2.26Ghz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the mpstat manpage:

> The interval parameter specifies the
>   amount of time in seconds between each
>   report. A  value of 0 (or no
>   parameters at all) indicates that
>   processors statistics are to be
>   reported for the time since system
>   startup (boot)

Running mpstat once only gives you a log-term estimate of usage. Running mpstat with an interval argument will give you more precise numbers.

This discrepancy is an accumulation of rounding errors, which grows with system activity and uptime. The actual statistics dispayed are collected from `/proc/stat` and `/proc/uptime`. The statistics are counted in USER_HZ (usually 100Hz, `getconf CLK_TCK` will confirm this), so your resolution is only 1/100th of a second; and a CPU does a lot in .01 seconds.

As an example:

```
$ cat /proc/stat; cat /proc/uptime

cpu  414821 51578 226720 66535103 73932 0 4548 0 0 0
cpu0 205014 22950 114302 33188492 36369 0 2071 0 0 0
cpu1 209807 28628 112418 33346611 37563 0 2477 0 0 0
<...>
335694.91 665351.03
```

On my workstation, which has only been up for a few days, we get the above numbers. If we calculate the percentage of the total time for the cpu stats compared to uptime, we get

```
(414821 + 51578 + 226720 + 66535103 + 73932 + 4548) / 335694.91 / 2
100.25%
```

There's a (not very helpful) note about process statistics in the `ps` man page as well.

> CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process. This is not ideal, and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to. CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the CPU usage is over 100%, however long one samples for it should average out at under 100.01% should it not?

Comment: @samarudge - I implied the reason by stating it was an "estimate", but I'll add more detail.